# Triangle identities as string diagrams

Tags: category-theory

From [Remark 2.2.9](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf):

[image]

How exactly do these diagrams translate to these triangle identities?

[image]

E.g. the first triangle identity has $F\eta$ and $\epsilon F$ in it; how to see them and their composition in the diagram?

Answer (score 2):

$F \eta$ is the top half of the first diagram, $\varepsilon F$ is the bottom half, and the composition is given by sticking the top half to the bottom half (note that if you cut the diagram in half it intersects the bottom $F$ line, then $G$, then the top $F$ line; this corresponds to the $FGF$ portion of the first triangle identity.

This is not quite the best way of drawing string diagrams for the triangle identities; ideally it should be clearer that functors correspond to line segments.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but it seems to me that it doesn't follow from what Leinster says about string diagrams. Namely, $F\eta$ and $\epsilon F$ are natural transformations. Natural transformations in string diagrams are supposed to be circled. Leinster's diagram for the triangle identities only has two circled things, and neither of them is $F\eta$ or $\epsilon F$.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Qiaochu's description with [an illustration from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_diagram#Example): [image: string diagram of adjunction]

Tom Leinster did mention how $1: F \Rightarrow F$ is drawn as a simple string without circles and how horizontal composition is depicted right before, but I agree with you and Qiaochu that the diagrams in the book is not clear.